# JavaScript - Ways of writing nested functions

Tags: javascript, function, nested

Is it okay to write nested functions like this?

```
var player = function () {
    //'use strict';

    var setLives = function () {
        return 3;
    };

    var lives = setLives();

    console.log(lives);
};

player();
```

In jsLint it would be this (quite ugly):

```
var player = function () {
    'use strict';

    var setLives = function () {
            return 3;
        },
        lives = setLives();

    console.log(lives);
};

player();
```

Most people seem to use the following approach:

```
var player = function () {
    //'use strict';

    function setLives() {
        return 3;
    }

    var lives = setLives();

    console.log(lives);
};

player();
```

Does it matter which method I use or would the latter be preferred?

Will it slow down the code or make no difference?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the quoted code, it makes no difference; it's purely a matter of style.

Sometimes, people prefer to write function expressions (`var setLives = function() { };`) because those occur during the step-by-step flow of the code in the function.

Sometimes, people prefer to write function declarations (`function setLives() { }`) because they are processed *before* the step-by-step flow of the code in the function.

If the definition of the function is going to be different depending on a condition...

```
if (someCondition) {
    // One definition for it
} else {
    // A different definition
}
```

...then it's necessary to use function expressions, not declarations.

Comment: Is there any scenario where it would matter?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen: If it were important that it happened in the step-by-step flow, then you'd need to use an expression. If it were important that it happen *before* the step-by-step flow, then you'd need to write a declaration. If the definition of the function varied based on a runtime condition, you'd need an expression.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a great example. I am using a condition and adding a method within it. I take it a function expression would be the right approach?

Comment: @Paddy: Yes indeed.